# Slide up one menu item with transition

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a menu that slides up on hover. My problem is that all the links slide up instead of just **one at a time**.

This is my html

```
<section id="content">
<div id="stuffhere">asd</div>
</section>
<div id="bottom">
  <nav id="links">
    <a href="#" id="m1" class="mlink">hello</a>
    <a href="#" id="m2" class="mlink">every</a>
    <a href="#" id="m3" class="mlink">one</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

and my css

```
body,html {
    height: 100%;
}
#content {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 40%;
}
#bottom {
    height: 60%;
    background: #444;
}
#links {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-spacing: 1em 0;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
.mlink {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em; 
    padding: 0.2em 0.6em;

    background: #ccc url('http://images.sodahead.com/polls/004017497/230735835_Emotes_face_wink_icon_answer_1_small.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 54px;

    transition: padding 0.2s linear, background-position 0.4s ease;
}
.mlink:hover { 
    padding-top: 2em; 
    background-position: 50% 10px;
}
```

And here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HfX2M/

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Like this?

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/HfX2M/1/

```
.mlink {
    display: inline;
```

When you have `table-cell` selected for your `display` property, it is assuming it is just that - a `table cell` in a `table row`. So when one expands, so do the rest.

Alternatively, you can also use `inline-block` to make them side by side, but maintain their `block` status for individual changes.

For more information on `display` properties, here is the W3 Standards Page for reference.

- http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display

---

If you want to maintain your padding (it is no longer assuming its a table so you have to make your own, use `inline-block` and an additional `margin`.

```
.mlink {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:.4em;
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/HfX2M/3/**

Comment: That seems to work. It messes up the padding though. Should I go about this another way?

Comment: Updated. If you believe this has helped you solve the problem, please select the green checkbox next to the voting arrows on your left.

Comment: This works great, thank you! I figured I had to use display:table-cell when it was inside a display:table.

Comment: No problem. Don't worry so much if it's 'right' or 'wrong', or you'll turn into a perfectionist that never gets anything done. There are hundreds of solutions to the simplest problems. Glad I can help.